# clear arraylist in java

Tags: java, arraylist

i try to make a 2D arrayList when i accept data and store it into a single arraylist then added it to the 2d arraylist so i clear the single array list in every loop and save the new row the problem in clearing data it clear all bast row and just save the newest one `enter code here`

```
public class main6 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
        BufferedReader b = new BufferedReader(in);
        int arrCol= scan.nextInt();     
        ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> arr = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
        ArrayList<String> x = new ArrayList<String>();
        
    for(int i = 0 ; i < arrCol ; i++) { 
        
        
        x.addAll(Arrays.asList(b.readLine().split("\\s"))); 
        arr.add(i,x);   
        x.clear();
    } 
         System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(arr.toArray()));
    }

}
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: this problem in hackerRank( https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/java-arraylist/problem)

Comment: At first, are you sure you understand the problem *what does it ask for*? I may be wrong, but your question seems quite confusing and unclear to me.

Comment: i just in the first step in the problem when i store the data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create the list in the for loop, so you have new instance for every addition:

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < arrCol ; i++) { 
    ArrayList<String> x = new ArrayList<String>();
    ...
```

... also, don't clear it afterwards...

Answer (score 1):

A couple pf things.

- Best practice is to assign to the interface type in lieu of the implementation.  And you're declaring your "2D" ArrayList incorrectly. So

```
    List<List<String>> arr = new ArrayList<>();
```

- No need to use an auxiliary List.  Just do it as follows:

```
    for(int i = 0 ; i < arrCol ; i++) {         
        arr.add(Arrays.asList(b.readLine().split("\\s")));
    }
```

- If you still want to create an explicit `ArrayList<>` implementation, then pass the output of `Arrays.asList` as an argument.  No need to use add or addAll.

```
    for(int i = 0 ; i < arrCol ; i++) {         
        arr.add(new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(b.readLine().split("\\s"))));
    }
```

- No need to convert to an array and do deep string conversion.  Lists don't need it.

```
    System.out.println(arr);
```

Note: One exception to to the first bullet.  Sometimes, a `List` implementation has more functionality in terms of `methods` that are not in the `List interface`.  In that case, if you want that functionality, then you need to assign to the implementation type rather than the interface type.  With `List` interfaces, I cannot recall having to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Update the for loop to instantiate the array list:

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < arrCol ; i++) { 
    
    ArrayList<String> x = new ArrayList<>();
    x.addAll(Arrays.asList(b.readLine().split("\\s"))); 
    arr.add(i,x);   
   
}
```

This way, the array list will be recreated for each loop and there is no need to clear it.

You can then remove the instantiation of the arraylist in the method body before the for-loop:

```
ArrayList<String> x = new ArrayList<String>();
```